# android: Trouble With Dialog Box

Tags: android, gps

I want to display the dialog with two buttons "ENABLE GPS" and "CANCEL" as soon as the application starts before the Launcher activity if the GPS is off otherwise if GPS is on, the launcher activity gets opened.

```
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

         // Declaring a Location Manager
          LocationManager locationManager;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled ) {
            // no GPS provider is enabled
            //Creating the Dialog box 
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext()).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Settings");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Enable GPS for accessing the Application");
            alertDialog.setButton("GPS Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//          creating Button i.e GPS Setting in the Dialog Box   
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    startActivity(new
                             Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
//          creating Button i.e Cancel in the Dialog Box
            alertDialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//                  Creating another Dialog when "Cancel" is pressed
                AlertDialog whencancelpressed = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
                whencancelpressed.setTitle("How to use the app");
                whencancelpressed.setMessage("Enter the contacts to whom you want to send the message.Double tap power button in emergency");
                whencancelpressed.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent pressedokay = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(pressedokay);
                    }
                });
                        whencancelpressed.show();   
                }
            });

                } else{
            // GPS provider is enabled
         }
```

I am using this code for displaying the dialog box before the launcher activity.But the application is forced closed while starting if the gps is off. Please guide me where i am doing wrong.

LOGCAT:

```
01-27 10:28:01.634: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(331): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 10:28:16.324: I/data(331): content://com.android.contacts/data/21
01-27 10:28:16.374: I/layoutLinear is not  null(331): not null
01-27 10:28:16.374: I/edittext is not  null(331): not null
01-27 10:28:23.484: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(331): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 10:28:25.324: I/data(331): content://com.android.contacts/data/1
01-27 10:28:25.354: I/layoutLinear is not  null(331): not null
01-27 10:28:25.364: I/edittext is not  null(331): not null
01-27 10:28:31.914: W/KeyCharacterMap(331): No keyboard for id 0
01-27 10:28:31.914: W/KeyCharacterMap(331): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-27 10:28:37.874: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(331): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 10:29:25.034: D/dalvikvm(331): GC_EXPLICIT freed 113K, 52% free 2610K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 54ms
01-27 10:45:24.084: W/KeyCharacterMap(386): No keyboard for id 0
01-27 10:45:24.084: W/KeyCharacterMap(386): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-27 10:45:24.284: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(386): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 10:49:08.635: W/KeyCharacterMap(439): No keyboard for id 0
01-27 10:49:08.635: W/KeyCharacterMap(439): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-27 10:49:08.824: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(439): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 11:28:38.884: W/KeyCharacterMap(546): No keyboard for id 0
01-27 11:28:38.884: W/KeyCharacterMap(546): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-27 11:28:39.064: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(546): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 11:29:15.374: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(546): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 11:29:37.554: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(546): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 11:29:38.574: I/data(546): content://com.android.contacts/data/19
01-27 11:29:38.615: I/layoutLinear is not  null(546): not null
01-27 11:29:38.624: I/edittext is not  null(546): not null
01-27 11:35:06.664: W/KeyCharacterMap(645): No keyboard for id 0
01-27 11:35:06.673: W/KeyCharacterMap(645): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-27 11:35:06.764: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(645): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 11:36:55.563: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(645): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 11:36:56.523: I/data(645): content://com.android.contacts/data/4
01-27 11:36:56.553: I/layoutLinear is not  null(645): not null
01-27 11:36:56.553: I/edittext is not  null(645): not null
01-27 11:36:59.604: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(645): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 11:37:00.155: I/data(645): content://com.android.contacts/data/19
01-27 11:37:00.174: I/layoutLinear is not  null(645): not null
01-27 11:37:00.184: I/edittext is not  null(645): not null
01-27 11:37:04.224: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(645): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 11:38:23.014: D/dalvikvm(645): GC_EXPLICIT freed 116K, 52% free 2596K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 60ms
01-27 11:43:08.804: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(742): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 11:45:33.185: D/dalvikvm(775): GC_EXPLICIT freed 56K, 53% free 2579K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 567ms
01-27 11:48:37.624: W/KeyCharacterMap(842): No keyboard for id 0
01-27 11:48:37.634: W/KeyCharacterMap(842): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-27 12:13:01.034: D/AndroidRuntime(878): Shutting down VM
01-27 12:13:01.034: W/dalvikvm(878): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zzz1/com.example.zzz1.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.example.zzz1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-27 12:13:01.054: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  ... 11 more
01-27 12:13:48.094: D/AndroidRuntime(911): Shutting down VM
01-27 12:13:48.094: W/dalvikvm(911): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zzz1/com.example.zzz1.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.example.zzz1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-27 12:13:48.114: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  ... 11 more
01-27 12:13:49.704: I/Process(911): Sending signal. PID: 911 SIG: 9
01-27 12:50:22.534: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(946): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 12:50:23.654: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(946): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 13:12:17.764: W/KeyCharacterMap(946): No keyboard for id 0
01-27 13:12:17.774: W/KeyCharacterMap(946): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-27 13:12:17.874: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(946): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-27 13:12:43.643: D/AndroidRuntime(946): Shutting down VM
01-27 13:12:43.653: W/dalvikvm(946): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zzz1/com.example.zzz1.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at com.example.zzz1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-27 13:12:43.664: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  ... 11 more
01-27 13:19:32.354: D/AndroidRuntime(1001): Shutting down VM
01-27 13:19:32.354: W/dalvikvm(1001): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zzz1/com.example.zzz1.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at com.example.zzz1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-27 13:19:32.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: A dialog is always attached to an activity, so it's not possible to show it before an activity.. I suggest to implement a gateway activity, this activity checks if gps is on of off, and start the corresponding activity from there

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan please have a look at the logcat

Comment: what is in `MainActivity.java:55`?

Comment: see answer of @user2247689, you need create() before showing

Comment: but its only showing the "GPS Setting" button not the other "Cancel" button.

Comment: Am i doing something wrong with the cancel button declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fix the problem:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Yourclassname.this).create();
```

Basically when you are working with Dialogs, they are tied down to a particular activity only, as opposed to Toasts that would live outside any given activity. Following this logic, rather than giving the `Builder` a context of your activity through `getApplicationContext()` - implying that the context could be of any activity, point out the exact activity the dialog is tied down to.

Hope the explanation is clear.

Since API something, sorry I don't remember, `setPositiveButton`, `setNegativeButton` and `setNeutralButton` are used to set the button for dialogs.

for e.g.

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(...)
```

The methods just make a difference in the positioning of your buttons declared.

Comment: dude, you are a rock star man ,, thank you very much.nailed it

Comment: but why was it failing with "getApplicationContent"

Comment: but its only showing the "GPS Setting" button not the other "Cancel" button .Am i doing something wrong with the cancel button declaration.

Comment: @bhanukaushik check edits and see if they help, if it does don't forget to accept the answer :)